# OALL8 is in an inconsistent state in Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Tags: database, oracle

We are getting an Exception in the production system like

```
"SQL state [null]; error code [17447]; OALL8 is in an inconsistent state"
```

while using `Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0` and `ojdbc6.jar`.
We are getting this exception in the production env, at dev environment its working fine.
I've googled many forums but i'm not able find .
plz help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This post ([Oracle: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679683/oracle-oall8-is-in-an-inconsistent-state)) suggest that it's an OJDBC bug that was related to the CURSOR_SHARING mode SIMILAR.

So:

1. Check with Oracle if a fix exists.
2. Check whether there are any differences in the settings between development and production and fix them.
3. Set Cursor Sharing to EXACT if it's set to a different mode.