# java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state on JBoss 6.1 EAP

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, jboss

OALL8 issue occurs while deploying an application on JBoss 6.1 EAP. 
Here is the stacktrace:

> java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:352) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:199)

I am using racojdbc14.jar to connect to the oracle database.

Oracle Database: Oracle 11g. It is an RAC Cluster

Can anyone please post the solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to upgrade your JDBC driver first, the fact it contains `14` in the name suggest it is a Java 1.4 driver, which means it is ancient and might have problems with newer Oracle versions.

Comment: Actually the issue got resolved when we restarted our setup. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution**: It is very hard to troubleshoot and the simplest solution is to upgrade your JDBC Driver. For more explanation please visit [this](http://www.oracleracexpert.com/2013/03/oall8-is-in-inconsistent-state.html) and [Oracle: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679683/oracle-oall8-is-in-an-inconsistent-state).

Comment: Thanks will make the changes and verify.